# StackOverflowError while running the arquillian test cases with wildfly server

Tags: eclipselink, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

Sometimes (not always) I am getting a stack overflow error while running the arquillian test cases on wildfly server.

```
2014-09-04 18:06:58,258 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.3.Final
2014-09-04 18:06:58,757 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) Failed to define class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.Helper in Module "deployment.ECommerceTest.ear.participant.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.VFSResourceLoader.getClassSpec(VFSResourceLoader.java:124)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:252) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4669) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4641) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4617) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4566) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.PersistenceWeaver.transform(PersistenceWeaver.java:127) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.classloader.JPADelegatingClassFileTransformer.transform(JPADelegatingClassFileTransformer.java:48) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DelegatingClassFileTransformer.transform(DelegatingClassFileTransformer.java:60)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:415) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4669) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4641) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4617) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4566) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.PersistenceWeaver.transform(PersistenceWeaver.java:127) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.classloader.JPADelegatingClassFileTransformer.transform(JPADelegatingClassFileTransformer.java:48) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DelegatingClassFileTransformer.transform(DelegatingClassFileTransformer.java:60)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:415) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.PersistenceWeaver.transform(PersistenceWeaver.java:80) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.classloader.JPADelegatingClassFileTransformer.transform(JPADelegatingClassFileTransformer.java:48) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DelegatingClassFileTransformer.transform(DelegatingClassFileTransformer.java:60)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:415) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.PersistenceWeaver.transform(PersistenceWeaver.java:80) [eclipselink.jar:2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.classloader.JPADelegatingClassFileTransformer.transform(JPADelegatingClassFileTransformer.java:48) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
```

Comment: Looks like an issue in EclipseLink. Are you not using the provided JPA provider?

Comment: We are using EclipseLink.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the classloader, as Line 80 of the EclipseLink PersistenceWeaver.transform method should not cause the transform method to again be called - the loader should be loading provider classes, not entity classes.  It seems like it is being registered on the classloader used to load its own classes.  The stack overflow is caused when it tries to log an exception, which then again causes EclipseLink classes to be loaded and transformed.  Check how the EclipseLink jar is added to the server and for JBoss bugs that might be related.